# How to access widgets created by slint DSL code?

Tags: rust

If I create widgets by Slint-Code, how do I access them from Rust-Code?
I couldn't find out how to access their properties, neither how to access them directly.

Example:

```
...
percent_widget := Text {
    text: percent_widget.percent;
    in-out property <string> percent: "??.? %";
}
...
```

This runs absolutely fine in the preview, but I can't find out how to either set the `percent_widget.percent` text property, or access the `percent_widget` widget from Rust-Code.

I'm using slint 1.1.1 and Rust 1.71.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the widget directly from Rust, but you can access the percent property if it's exposed in the root of your application, or in a global singleton. So you can do either this:

(using slint inline in Rust, but of course this also works with a separate file)

```rust
slint::slint! {

import { VerticalBox } from "std-widgets.slint";
export component Demo inherits Window {
    // exposed to Rust, access via Demo::set_percent() and Demo::get_percent()
    // Create an alias
    in-out property percent <=> percent_widget.percent;

    VerticalBox {
        percent_widget := Text {
            text: percent_widget.percent;
            in-out property <string> percent: "??.? %";
        }
    }
}
}

fn main() {
    let demo = Demo::new().unwrap();
    demo.set_percent("25".into());
    demo.run().unwrap();
}
```

or you can also use a singleton, if you don't want to forward the property:

```rust
slint::slint! {

import { VerticalBox } from "std-widgets.slint";

// global that's exported -> accessible via Rust
export global PercentageAdapter {
    in property <string> percent;
}

export component Demo inherits Window {
    VerticalBox {
        percent_widget := Text {
            text: PercentageAdapter.percent;
        }
    }
}
}

fn main() {
    let demo = Demo::new().unwrap();
    demo.global::<PercentageAdapter>().set_percent("25".into());
    demo.run().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Slint makes it really unnecessary complicated. I hope this gets fixed soon.